# How to mimic generics in XML Schema without extension or substitution?

Tags: xml, generics, xsd

Say I have this XML fragment:

```
<values>
  <value>1</value>
  <value>2</value>
</values>
```

I want to make a Schema for which uses generic type inteference. This should be done `xsi:type` whichout redefining the structure over and over again in the schema. I want to do it once and use it. Desired datatypes would be int, date, string.

In my opinion, this is not possible in XML Schema, I have to define a abstract element and create an extension every datatype. At runtime I have to declare a concrete `xsi:type`.

Comment: I don't see anyway to do this either.  You want parameterized types, but there is no such thing in XSD.

Comment: Kevin, yes this is a pity. I have four data types: string, int, float, date. I have to perform `xs:restriction` on every definition to narrow the type. Bloats the schema completely.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do it would be to play games with namespace and namespaceLocation - tricking the schema into fetching a different include file somehow. It wouldn't be portable.

Trying to do what you want in XMLSchema without extends is like trying to do it in Java without extends. You want to do X without using the language features that exist precisely to do X. Use the language the way it wants to be used.